# How to install drivers for Microsoft Kinect on Windows Vista

Tags: windows, windows-vista, kinect

I have a Kinect sensor for XBox, and I´d like to try to develop some applications for Kinect. Problem is that when I´ve tried to install SDK or runtime, an error occurred. Namely, I have an unsuitable operating system (Vista Business 64) - it needs Win7 or Win8.

Is there any chance of installing drivers on Vista that work with Kinect on this operating system?

Comment: AFAIK the drivers are Windows7 minimum. I fear that trying to use them on Vista might fail because of components that Vista might lack. In theory it could be components that could work on Vista, on the other it might code kernel related elements, but either way, it would take a lot of time to find all dependencies and find workarounds that might or might not work. It might be easier to: upgrade to Win7/install Windows7 on a different partition as a secondary os to boot to/use a virtualization/borrow a computer from a friend :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this thread in MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/kinectsdk/thread/cc371fef-1a8e-4c20-91cf-1ee8a78c02d6/#80b2952c-f3a0-4de7-bb9f-173e2d1b95dc) it's at least partially possible, citing:

> I used ORCA (microsoft msi editor) to edit the installer, to remove the check for windows 7(table: launchcondition; edit 'Installed OR (VersionNT >= 601)' to 'Installed OR (VersionNT >= 400)' ), and the SDK happily installed. Also all drivers seem to register correct, and the camera seems to work. Only the audio seems to need some extra work.

But it's certainly not supported and I'd strongly suggest developing Kinect apps on Win 7 or 8

Answer (score 2):

The official Microsoft Kinect for Windows requires Windows 7+.  Per the Kinect for Windows website:

> The SDK includes drivers for using the Kinect for Windows sensor on a **computer running Windows 8, Windows 7, or Windows Embedded Standard 7**.

If Vista is a requirement you may want to try OpenNI or `libfreenect`.  I am unsure of their requirements, though.